# How to delete or add imageviews to layout in android?

Tags: android, imageview

I am making a draw the shortest straw game and wondering if I can delete or add image views to my layout in MainAcitvity

For example, the app starts with 3 image views/straws by default, and when the user increases or decreases the number of straws. It will add or delete the views/straws.

Or I can create 5 views, and set the images to visible or invisible to match the number that user inputted. Or is there a better solution for this?

Comment: Yes you can remove views on the fly or add them as needed.

Comment: Would be easier to say if you had code but showing `visible` or `gone` sounds fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use View.GONE instead of deleting. With View.GONE the view wont take any space so it is as it is deleted from the user's view. IMO it is the best way.

If you want to show your image.

```
image.setVisibility(View.VISIBILE);
```

If you want to hide your image.

```
image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

But if you insist on deleting use `removeViewAt()` or `removeView()`.

Comment: Can I delete the view instead of setting the visibility of the images? Thanks

Comment: @XinChen, no need to delete the view. With View.GONE it will act as it is deleted since it will not take any space. Removing then adding is not a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove / add view dynamically, this is example how to add view:

```
LinearLayout ll;
ll = new LinearLayout(this);
TextView tv = new TextView(instance);
tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.TOP);    
tv.setText("Halo Dunia");
tv.setTextSize(20);
ll.addView(tv);
```

and how to delete it:

```
ll.removeView(tv);
```